# Save record embedded in iframe

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

### Scenario

CRM2011, rollup 13

Account form with iframe, that displays contact form. Requirement is that when user press "save" button on account form, contact in iframe should be also saved.

### OnSave event code

```
var iframeXrmPage = Xrm.Page.getControl("IFRAME_contact").getObject().contentWindow.Xrm.Page;
iframeXrmPage.data.entity.save();  //error: Unable to get property 'entity' of undefined or null reference
```

I can get Xrm object of iframe, but it has `data` and `ui` members set to `null`.

Is there any way to call `save()` in iframe using Xrm.Page? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

var iframeXrmPage = Xrm.Page.getControl("IFRAME_contact").getObject().contentWindow.contentIFrame.Xrm.Page;